# React onsubmit change depreciated refs to updated code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some code which catches a submitted form data.

Here it is:

```
class UserInfo extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = {};
    for (const field in this.refs) {
      formData[field] = this.refs[field].value;
    }
    console.log('-->', formData);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input ref="fullname" className="fullname" type='text' name="fullname"/>
            <input ref="email" className="email" type='tel' name="email"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserInfo;
```

The above works fine but refs are depreciated so my question is...

How can I change this refs to non-depreciated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this :

```
   <input ref="fullname" className="fullname" type='text' name="fullname"/>
    <input ref="email" className="email" type='tel' name="email"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

to this:

```
   <input ref={fullname => this.fullname =fullname} className="fullname" type='text' name="fullname"/>
    <input ref={email => this.email = email} className="email" type='tel' name="email"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

now the reference is stored in this.fullname and this.email. 
don't forget to check if they are null.

I hope it helps.

Comment: So in your example solution I could in theory rename ref to data or theData or anything?

Comment: @KevinPorche ref is a function the name of the parameter doesn't matter.

Comment: But isn't the function ref depreciated? - See: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @KevinPorche only Using string literals in ref attributes is deprecated